# How do you manage user domains?

Tags: dns, hosting

I was working on a publishing platform of sorts where users can sign up and create a blog for themselves. Currently I was planning to host it on https://vercel.com. How would I set up something so that users can use their own domain and get only their blog on that domain. I'm sorry if the question is a bit too broad but if someone could point me in a general direction I would be very grateful. The only thing that comes to mind would be setting up a DNS server and then using that to route the users domain but I don't know if that's the right way to go about it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The users would have to point to your nameservers on their DNS record if they control the domain.  You can learn more about nameservers in this article: https://serverfault.com/questions/355887/why-does-dns-work-the-way-it-does

What you can do is provide them with a subdomain of the domain of your publishing platform such as:

```
user1.publisher.com
user2.publisher.com
```

Subdomain records reside within the authoritative record for a domain, so you can add and remove them easily.

Comment: Hey there thanks for the reply but I have subdomains working. For example I have user.myapp.com working perfectly with a unique page for each user. However how can I allow user.com to have the same content as user.myapp.com. Would I have to tell them to add a CNAME record & would I also have to add a record on my end? Sorry for being annoying this is just confusing me a lot.

Comment: Yes, you could have them add a CNAME record for their user.com to point to your user.myapp.com.